How to align different entries with same column elements but different positions under just one column in Pandas?
I have time series data that looks like this:



time
Team A
Team B
Team C




14:00:00
2pts
0pts
0pts


time
Team B
Team A
Team C


14:01:00
3pts
2pts
0pts


time
Team B
Team A
Team C


14:02:00
3pts
2pts
2pts



And so on, except there are lots of teams and lots of entries. The entries list the teams ranked by points, so the team with the most points will be on the leftmost column. I want to turn this into a chart, but obviously the rankings can change and I can't just delete the labels on every other row and make it work. How do I transform the frame in pandas so it looks like this:



time
Team A
Team B
Team C




14:00:00
2pts
0pts
0pts


14:01:00
2pts
3pts
0pts


14:02:00
2pts
3pts
2pts



I'm not sure if I should be creating a new frame out of this or if I can manipulate the existing one in place.

Example
import pandas as pd
data = {'time': ['14:00:00', 'time', '14:01:00', 'time', '14:02:00'], 
        'Team A': ['2pts', 'Team B', '3pts', 'Team B', '3pts'], 
        'Team B': ['0pts', 'Team A', '2pts', 'Team A', '2pts'], 
        'Team C': ['0pts', 'Team C', '0pts', 'Team C', '2pts']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df:
       time  Team A  Team B  Team C
0  14:00:00    2pts    0pts    0pts
1      time  Team B  Team A  Team C
2  14:01:00    3pts    2pts    0pts
3      time  Team B  Team A  Team C
4  14:02:00    3pts    2pts    2pts

Code
split dfs and use concat
dfs = [
    df.iloc[[i]].set_axis(df.iloc[i - 1], axis=1)
    for i in df.index[1:]
    if i % 2 == 0
]
out = pd.concat([df.iloc[[0]]] + dfs, ignore_index=True)

out:
       time Team A Team B Team C
0  14:00:00   2pts   0pts   0pts
1  14:02:00   2pts   3pts   2pts
2  14:02:00   2pts   3pts   2pts


since time is repeated in the first column, you can use that, and avoid the iteration within python : df.loc[df.time.ne('time')]

@sammywemmy iteration need for set_axis. The columns are not uniform, which is why i used a loop.
